# Date.UTC output is wrong

Tags: javascript

Im trying to convert unix timestamps into human readable format by using `Date.UTC(2017,09,23);` running this will give me `1508716800000` upon checking on this website https://www.epochconverter.com/ the output displayed is October 23, 2017 which should be September 23, 2017. Is my code correct or  maybe incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Month should be a number between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)